# Datepicker add css day

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I use jquery ui datepicker, I would like to color a box the day according to a time array. The problem is that I want to put color on different days without having to create all css class, just by adding the hexadecimal color. This is my code:

```
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var month = date.getMonth()+1;
            var day =  date.getDate();

            if (month < 10) {
                month = '0' + month;
            }

            if (day < 10) {
                day = '0' + day;
            }

            return [true, $.inArray(the_day, tab_days) >= 0 ? "odd" : ''];
        }
    });
```

Css class:

```
.odd a.ui-state-default {
    color:white;
    background-color: red;
    background: red;
}
```

This version works but every day have the same color, I would do something like that:

```
      $(this).css("background-color", hexa color);
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is convert RGB to Hex.  Like this

```
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

$(this).css("background-color", rgbToHex(rIn,gIn,bIn));
```

Just change your input values to whatever you want.